# how to load html image files on the python tornado

Tags: python, html, image, tornado

I want to make a some web page. but i can't load image files in the html. I don't know why this situation is happen. I attached HTML code, python tornado code.
could you help me?

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>The GIF standard allows moving images.</p>
<img src="programming.gif" alt="Computer man" style="width:148px;hei    ght:148px;">
</body>
</html>
```

PYTHON-TORNADO FILE

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.httpserver

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.render("html_image_05.html")

application = tornado.web.Application([
(r"/",Handler)
])
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(80)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and this is message code when i execute this code.

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /eh5v.files/html5video/test.jpg (127.0.0.1) 0.56ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /eh5v.files/html5video/html5ext.js (127.0.0.1) 0.41ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /eh5v.files/html5video/test.m4v (127.0.0.1) 0.48ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /eh5v.files/html5video/test.jpg (127.0.0.1) 0.34ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /eh5v.files/html5video/test.webm (127.0.0.1) 0.36ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm solved the problem. 
that is way.

Python file code (Fixed)

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.httpserver

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("html_image_05.html")

application = tornado.web.Application([
(r"/",Handler),
(r"/(programming.gif)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path':'./'}) <--Add!
])

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(80)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

That's solution about connecting image with html and python file.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in official Tornado documentation.

> A `StaticFileHandler` is configured automatically if you pass the `static_path` keyword argument to `Application`. This handler can be customized with the `static_url_prefix`, `static_handler_class`, and `static_handler_args` settings.

Current version is *Release 6.0.4*

It means you should be able to do something like this:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.httpserver

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.render("html_image_05.html")

application = tornado.web.Application([
(r"/",Handler)
],

static_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"static"))

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(80)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and after you've placed image in **static** folder you would slightly alter your `.html` file by saying:

```
<img src="static/programming.gif" alt="Computer man" style="width:148px; hei  ght:148px;">
```